# add Camunda to existing project

Tags: spring, spring-boot, camunda

is it possible to add camunda BPMN to the existing spring boot project and access it using localhost:8080. so I have Spring boot mvc application which already have endpoint for index
localhost:8080/ how to access to camunda panel ?

Answer (score 0):

Camunda Cockpit has its own PATH under `/camunda/`... so it wont interfere with any other pages you are publishing.

Just call `http://localhost:8080/camunda` directly instead of `:8080/`.

If you have any problems, disable the camunda `/` redirect via application properties:

`camunda.bpm.webapp.index-redirect-enable=false`